# How to compare Java function object to a specific method?

Tags: java

Given the following code:

```
BooleanSupplier booleanSupplier = this::someMethod;
```

How can `booleanSupplier` be later compared to `this::someMethod`? With `booleanSupplier == this::someMethod`, Java complains that `this::someMethod` isn't expected in that context.

Comment: This might help you.
https://www.codementor.io/eh3rrera/using-java-8-method-reference-du10866vx

Comment: what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: You can only compare whether they are the same reference. You can't determine that they reference the same thing. i.e. they would always do the same thing.

Comment: What you can do is create a field `final BooleanSupplier someMethod = this::someMethod` which you can reuse and compare `if (booleanSupplier == someMethod)`